# Find the most identical string block, given a smaller string

Tags: python

Basically I need to check if inside a string block, there is another string contained in it (both are only numbers), so my first attempt was to just do a:

```
if strSmall in strBig:
    #do stuff
```

But the problem is that my strBig comes from an OCR, and sometimes it missinterpret some digits, failing to find it.

I tried using Levenshtein distance, but the problem is that I don't only need to find the similarity, I need to find where, so I tried looping trough my big string checking the ratio of every string contained in it, for example:

```
bigStr = 123456
smallStr = 45

check similarity betwwen 12 and 45
check similarity betwwen 23 and 45
check similarity betwwen 34 and 45
and so forth
get the most similar substring
```

But as you guess, it is extremely time consuming.
Is there a way to accomplish this with a better time complexity?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it fast with list comprehension, firstly creating substrings of big string and then comparing them with the small string. Also, you will need a threshold even if you use Levenstein to decide if it a misspelled small string inside the big one. In this function, the threshold is how many similar characters there are in the same position.

```
def similars(big_string, small_string, threshold):
    z=[big_string[i:i+len(small_string)] for i in range(0,round(len(big_string)))]
    f=[i for i in z if  sum([x==y for (x,y) in zip(list(i), list(small_string))])>threshold]
    return (f)
```

Examples:

```
big_string = '123456'
small_string = '45'

similars(big_string,small_string,1)
['45']


big_string='nweok ncwoejn ckljwncjkwdn e dkjwnedij3en wjdh2othis is a tast klxjwnocwlkj'
small_string='this is a test'

similars(big_string,small_string,10)
['this is a tast']
#this was a misspelled small_stringinside the big string
```

Comment: This is a very good answer, because the OCR will swap some characters, your function checks characters in the same place, better than Levenshtein which do some kind of fuzzy algorithm. And the time really went down using list comprehension.